# Unable to Change type Date format in ext js 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs5, extjs6.2

I am new to the Ext JS. My requirement is to show date in "d/m/Y h:i" format in the UI.

Below are the classes that I have created :

1. A.java : From this file I get the date in "2015-01-24T14:31:11" format.
2. Model Js file : `fields: [{name: 'date', type: 'date'}]`
3. Store Js file :

   ```
      loadData : function () return new PromisedRequest()
           .get("/test/{empId}")
           .then(function (data) {
               Ext.each(data, function(rec) {                   
                   var dt = new Date();                 
                  rec.date = Ext.Date.format(dt, 'd/m/Y h:i');
               });                
               return data;
           })
           .then(null, null, null, this);
   ```
4. View js file :
   Each row is rendered in textarea with some other text also from the store.
   When I use `new Date()` then it get successfully overwritten. When I try to format date from json rec then it wont get updated in store.

   I am thankful if anyone has face the same issue and have solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to specify the [dateFormat](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Date.html#cfg-dateFormat) within your model's date field - Like so:

```
{
    name: 'date',
    type: 'date',
    dateFormat: 'd/m/Y h:i'
}
```

You're also able to manipulate fields with [calculate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Date.html#cfg-calculate) for other cases to avoid manipulating data in the store upon load.